# error while compiling

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate-mapping

error on line : config.AddAssembly("Hibernatetest");

Error Message  : Could not compile the mapping document: Hibernatetest.Company.hbm.xml

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
            ISessionFactory factory;
            config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
            config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect");
            config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver , "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver");
            config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Chitty;Integrated Security=True");
            config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.Core.ProxyFactoryFactory ,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.Core");
            config.AddAssembly("Hibernatetest");
```

this is the company xml file

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-3.0" namespace="Hibernatetest"
assembly="Hibernatetest">
  <class name="Company" table="Company">
    <id name="company_Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="company_name" type="string" />
    <property name="company_email" type="string"/>
    <property name="company_size" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
I don't know why you put your namespace in the hbm file:
Hibernatetest.Company.hbm.xml
and also put the namespace in the class name:

This is how should look:

```
Company.hbm.xml
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-3.0" namespace="Hibernatetest"
assembly="Hibernatetest">
  <class name="Company" table="Company">
    <id name="company_Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="company_name" type="string" />
    <property name="company_email" type="string"/>
    <property name="company_size" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Also you can get rid off the type but it's a good practice to put the column attribute in a property.

Answer (score 0):

The class name is wrong, write the class name with the full namespace ( if you don't want to specify the namespace at the mapping level. The offending part is for sure the comma after the Company. And btw, if it does not solve, please add the class too in your question: it looks strange you have defined a c# class with properties named "company_name".